# Haskell: Recursive Matrix Kronecker Product and Recursive Flattened Rendering of Multidimensional Block Matrices

Tags: haskell, recursion, matrix, matrix-multiplication, typeclass

I was implementing a kronecker product function in Haskell for learning, and everything works well, 
except that I haven't figured out the correct implementation for a higher-order kroneckerProduct that 
can take a sub-kroneckerProduct as a parameter, which also led me to think about how to render the 
block matrix produced by the kroneckerProduct.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.List (intercalate, transpose)
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
import Control.Applicative (Applicative, pure, (<$>), (<*>))

newtype Matrix a = Matrix { getMatrix :: [[a]] }

instance Functor Matrix where
    fmap f = Matrix . (fmap (fmap f)) . getMatrix 

instance Applicative Matrix where
    pure x = Matrix [[x]]
    (Matrix as) <*> (Matrix bs) = Matrix $ zipWith (zipWith id) as bs

instance (Show a) => Show (Matrix a) where 
    show = (intercalate "\n") . fmap (unwords . fmap show) . getMatrix

scalarProduct :: (Num a) => a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
scalarProduct scalar matrix = (* scalar) <$> matrix

hadamardProduct :: (Num a) => Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
hadamardProduct matrix1 matrix2 = (*) <$> matrix1 <*> matrix2

-- The kronecker product M1 ⊗ M2, results in a block matrix.
-- It is a matrix that has elements that are also matrices, 
-- this makes it somewhat multidimensional tensor. 
-- The resulting block matrix has the same dimensions as M1. 
-- Every resulting element M1M2ij is equal to M1ij × M2. 
-- Assuming M1 contains scalars, this would mean every element 
-- in the resulting matrix requires a further scalar multiplication. 
-- But it could also be some other multiplication method.
-- This requires a RankNTypes
kroneckerProduct :: (a -> Matrix b -> Matrix b) -> Matrix a -> Matrix b -> Matrix (Matrix b)
kroneckerProduct f m1 m2 = (`f` m2) <$> m1

-- Flattening a block matrix produced by kroneckerProduct into a normal Matrix.
-- This works by assuming a quad layer matrix: [[[[...]]]].
-- We tranpose the middle 2,then concat the outside 2, and concat the inner 2.
-- This ends up bringing out the inner block matrices into the outside.
-- The resulting size of the new matrix is rowA*colA * rowB*colB, 
-- where A is the outer Matrix, and B is the inner Matrix.
flattenBlock :: Matrix (Matrix a) -> Matrix a
flattenBlock blockMatrix = Matrix $ dilate $ getMatrix2 blockMatrix
    where 
        dilate = (fmap concat) . concat . (fmap transpose)
        getMatrix2 = getMatrix . fmap getMatrix

incrementingMatrix :: Int -> Int -> Matrix Int
incrementingMatrix rowSize colSize = Matrix $ chunksOf colSize [1..(rowSize * colSize)]
```

So this works:

```
> let blockMatrix1 = kroneckerProduct scalarProduct (incrementingMatrix 2 2) (incrementingMatrix 2 2)
> putStrLn $ show $ flattenBlock blockMatrix1
> let blockMatrix2 = kroneckerProduct hadamardProduct blockMatrix1 (incrementingMatrix 2 2)
> putStrLn $ show $ flattenBlock blockMatrix2
```

However we cannot compile this (but mathematically it should be possible):

```
> let recursiveKro = kroneckerProduct (kroneckerProduct scalarProduct)
```

I end up with an "Occurs Check":

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ Matrix b
Expected type: Matrix b -> Matrix b -> Matrix b
  Actual type: Matrix b -> Matrix b -> Matrix (Matrix b)
Relevant bindings include
  recursiveKro :: Matrix (Matrix b) -> Matrix b -> Matrix (Matrix b)
    (bound at <interactive>:240:5)
In the first argument of ‘kroneckerProduct’, namely
  ‘(kroneckerProduct scalarProduct)’
In the expression:
  kroneckerProduct (kroneckerProduct scalarProduct)
```

So what would I need to change, to make the above expression possible?

Furthermore, if it becomes possible to create multilayered block matrices, we would need to extend the `flattenBlock` function to be recursive as well.

I imagine it should look like:

```
flattenBlockRecursive m = fmap flattenBlockRecursive $ Matrix $ (concat . (fmap transpose) . (fmap concat)) (getMatrix $ fmap getMatrix $ m)
```

And would need to use some sort of typeclass recursion, but I attempted it with multi-parameter typeclasses but couldn't make sense of it.

So to reiterate:

1. How do I change the kroneckerProduct function to allow greater flexibility in accepting a sub-kroneckerProduct function?
2. How would I then flatten the multi-layered block matrix and render it?

Comment: The type error is sound - `kroneckerProduct` expects something of type `x -> Matrix y -> Matrix y` but the type of `kroneckerProduct scalarProduct` is `Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix (Matrix a)` - y unifies with both `Matrix a` and `a` in this case, giving the infinite type error. I think the type of `kroneckerProduct` is wrong, it is a binary associative operator, so its type should reflect that. I think the function you want has type `Ring a => Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix (Matrix a)` - since matrices form a `Ring` this gives you the "infinite tower" of products you want.

Comment: Is there an existing typeclass called Ring that I can use?

Comment: I'm sure there are many as any search engine can reveal - but perhaps you are looking for a [recommendation.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/algebra-4.2/docs/Numeric-Ring-Class.html)

Comment: The kroneckerProduct can use any kind of multiplication though. And the kind of multiplication sometimes has to be specified, not just through typeclass polymorphism. So I'm not understanding how `kroneckerProduct :: Ring a => Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix (Matrix a)`.

Comment: When you say "kroneckerProduct can use any kind of multiplication" I assume you mean that it doesn't need the entire ring structure (perhaps just a group?) - then the type can be `kroneckerProduct :: Group a => Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix (Matrix a)` and of course matrices are still a group. If you don't want the uniqueness property that typeclasses enforce, you can reify classes as records and have `kroneckerProduct :: Group a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix (Matrix a)` - these concerns are entirely orthogonal, I think.

Comment: No I mean that a kroneckerProduct can be partially applied with any other matrix multiplication function as the first argument. It's possible for there to be `kroneckerProduct scalarProduct` or `kroneckerProduct (kroneckerProduct scalarProduct)` ... etc.